# save forms with OneToOneField and Class-based views

Tags: django, forms, django-views, one-to-one

#### models.py

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
expediente          = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
nombre              = models.CharField(max_length=100)
paterno             = models.CharField(max_length=100)
materno             = models.CharField(max_length=100)
estado              = models.ForeignKey(Estado,related_name='Estado_set')
municipio           = models.ForeignKey(Municipio,related_name='Municipio_set')`enter code here`
localidad           = models.ForeignKey(Localidad,related_name='Localidad_set')
calle               = models.CharField(max_length=100)
noExterior          = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
noInterior          = models.CharField(max_length=4,blank=True, null=True)
...



def __unicode__(self):
     name = "%s - %s %s %s"%(self.expediente,self.nombre,self.paterno,self.materno)
        return name

class FamParentesco(models.Model):
    GENERO = (
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
        ('M', 'Masculino')
    )
    paciente            = models.ForeignKey(Paciente)
    nombre              = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    edad                = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,blank=True, null=True)
    sexo                = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENERO)
    parentesco          = models.ForeignKey(Parentesco)
    escolaridad         = models.ForeignKey(Escolaridad,blank=True, null=True)
    ocupacion           = models.ForeignKey(Ocupacion,blank=True, null=True)
    estadoCivil         = models.ForeignKey(EstadoCivil,blank=True, null=True)
    ingreso             = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre

class EgresoMensual(models.Model):
    paciente            = models.OneToOneField(Paciente, unique=True, related_name='egresomensual')
    renta               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    alimentacion        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    luzaguacomb         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    educacion           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    vestidop            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    pasajes             = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    abonos              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    otros               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)
    total               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)

class OtrosIngresos(models.Model):
    paciente            = models.OneToOneField(Paciente)
    propiedades         = models.BooleanField()
    detalleprop         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rentas              = models.BooleanField()
    negocio             = models.BooleanField()
    detallearticulos    = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Vivienda(models.Model):
    paciente            = models.OneToOneField(Paciente)
    tipo                = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    piso                = models.BooleanField()
    techo               = models.BooleanField()
    ventana             = models.BooleanField()
    habitaciones        = models.IntegerField()
    agua                = models.BooleanField()
    excreta             = models.BooleanField()
    basura              = models.BooleanField()
    energia             = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hacinamiento        = models.BooleanField()
    promiscuidad        = models.BooleanField()

class Observaciones(models.Model):
    paciente            = models.OneToOneField(Paciente)
    observaciones       = models.TextField()
```

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import EgresoMensual, Observaciones, OtrosIngresos, Paciente, FamParentesco, Vivienda

class PacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Paciente

ParentescoFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Paciente, FamParentesco)

class EgresoMensualForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EgresoMensual
        exclude = ('paciente')

class ObservacionesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Observaciones

class OtrosIngresosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OtrosIngresos

class ViviendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vivienda
```

#### views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView 

from .models import Paciente, FamParentesco
from .forms import PacienteForm, ParentescoFormSet, ObservacionesForm, ViviendaForm, OtrosIngresosForm, EgresoMensualForm

class PatientCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'add_expediente.html'
    model = Paciente
    form_class = PacienteForm
    success_url = 'success/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form_class()
        family_form = ParentescoFormSet()
        egreso_form = EgresoMensualForm()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  family_form=family_form,
                                  egreso_form = egreso_form))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        family_form = ParentescoFormSet(self.request.POST)
        egreso_form = EgresoMensualForm(self.request.POST, instance=request.paciente.egresomensual)
        if (form.is_valid() and family_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, family_form, egreso_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, family_form, egreso_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, family_form, egreso_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        family_form.instance = self.object
        egreso_form.instance = self.object
        family_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, family_form, egreso_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                   family_form=family_form,
                                   egreso_form=egreso_form))
```

As I can display forms in my view with OneToOneField relationships?

I was trying to create a relationship with EgresoMesual Pacientee, going by the GET method creates me the form

But to go through the POST method and relate the form EgresoMensualForm

egreso_form = EgresoMensualForm (self.request.POST, instance = request.paciente.egresomensual)

I mark error:

AttributeError at / ece / file /

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'patient'

How can I create a single form that takes models: EgresoMensual, OtrosIngresos, Holiday Observations